# how to stop rowcommand event from getting executed in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with checkbox inside `asp:TemplateField`. I wish to select multiple checkboxes and on button click I want to add those selected rows in another page which consists of the `Repeater`.Also I want to give the ability to the user to select a single row when any of the row is clicked.

My problem is when I click any of the checkbox,the rowcommand gets fired and one record gets added to the repeater.
I wish to prevent this rowcommand event to get fired when checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Kindly guide me on this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: set autopostback property to false for that check box/

Comment: I did try that, but it does not work.The rowcommand still gets fired.Is there any other workaround for that ?

Comment: are u trying to add rows on checkbox check event ???

Comment: I assume that you've added javascript to the complete row so that the row-command gets fired when the user clicks the row. The checkbox is part of the row, so you need to add the JS instead to all cells but the checkbox-cell.

Comment: please post your html as we are not getting what properties you have set .

Comment: @Madhu: I am trying to check multiple rows and on button click I want to add the selected rows on another page that consist of a repeater

Comment: @Tim: Currently yes I am calling the javascript for complete row,Can you tell me how can we skip the javascript for checkboxes, it should be done in RowDataBound right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you've added javascript on the complete row so that the row gets selected when the user clicks the row. The checkbox is part of the row what is the reason for the immediate postback. So you need to add the Javascript to all cells without the checkbox-cell.

You could use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
       var chechBoxColumnIndex=1;
       var highlightColor = "yellow"; 
       var cells=(e.Row.Cells
                   .Cast<TableCell>()
                   .Where((r,index) => index != chechBoxColumnIndex));

        foreach(var c in cells.Cast<TableCell>()){
            //note: you need to set EnableEventValidation to false in this page
            c.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            c.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            c.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';bgColor=this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor;this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor= '" + highlightColor + "';";
            c.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=bgColor;";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited** according to your comment.

Comment: Current I have this code in RowDataBound:                         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
                                     "bgCol = this.style.backgroundColor; this.style.backgroundColor = '" + HighlightColor +
                                     "';this.style.cursor = 'hand'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor = bgCol;");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:SelectRow('" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')");
            }

Comment: Thank you Tim,Can you please explain me Cast<TableCell> because I am getting an error on var cells = (e.Row.Cells.
Cast<TableCell> , Cast does not show in the intellisense. Error:TableCellCollection does not contain a definition for Cast and also about the invalied arguments.

Comment: @Warrior: add the appropriate `using` directive to the class, in this case `using System.Linq;`. It would be helpful to tag the language and framework version next time(f.e. `C#` and `c#-4.0`). I could have shown you VB.NET code instead.